# What is the name of this distribution family?

Tags: confidence-interval, density-function, pareto-distribution

I am trying to identify this probability density function so I can read up on it to find confidence intervals for $\theta$:

$$f(x;\theta,v)=\frac{\theta v^\theta}{x^{\theta+1}}I_{[v,\infty)]}(x);\ \theta>0,\ v>0$$

where $I$ is an indicator function.

Comment: Pareto is your friend.

Comment: @wolfies ... expanded to a couple of sentences and maybe a link, I'd call that a good answer.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/497119/119261